# How do I run this script in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

This is my script from Oracle but I have problems running it on MySQL.

```
SELECT s.branch_no, SUM(s.staff_salary)
from staff AS s

HAVING SUM(staff_salary) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(S2.staff_salary))
                            FROM staff AS S2
                            GROUP BY S2.BRANCH_NO)
                            GROUP BY s.branch_no;
```

The error that I get when I run it on MySQL:

```
SELECT s.branch_no, SUM(s.staff_salary)
from staff AS s

HAVING SUM(staff_salary) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(S2.staff_salary))
                            FROM staff AS S2
                            GROUP BY S2.branch_no)
                            GROUP BY s.branch_no
 LIMIT 0, 50
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY s.branch_no LIMIT 0, 50' at line 7

Comment: `GROUP BY` needs to come before `HAVING` (at least in MS SQL, probably the same in MySQL). I just looked at the pl sql docs and it appears to be the same syntax there.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, [pretty much everything but order by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) usually comes before the HAVING clause. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges group by

Comment: don't forget leave `LIMIT` clause at the end

Comment: Learn SQL syntax, fix your query, then run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try seperating the query into small subqueries.

In your case I would try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(staff_salary) sm , branch_no
    FROM staff 
    GROUP BY BRANCH_NO
) s
ORDER BY sm DESC LIMIT 1
```